# Making a large collection as observable affect the performance

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application using jQuery Mobile and KnockoutJs. I've a collection that can grow upto 500. I've set the collection as observable and also all the properties (max 4) of each object in the collection as observables. Will this affect the performance of the application?

Comment: Having large numbers of observables will begin to slow down your application.  I guess it is up to you to consider if these really need to be observable, or whether you could put in paging to limit the number on the page at the same time

Comment: @Thewads Thanks for the pagination idea. I think it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test case and time it. That's the only reliable way to answer performance questions.

Comment: I need a windows phone to do an accurate test. Thanks for your reply but it's not helping me. I asked the question to get answers from pros who might have already done these tests and know about the performance implications of observables.